# How to copy a file in C?

Tags: c, file, unix

I'm trying to write a function to copy a file in C. I need it to work with any type of file whether it's a text, binary file or some other format. This is what I have right now, but it seems like my implementation is broken. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
// Copies the file from source to destination and returns number of bytes written
ssize_t copy_file(char* source, char* destination, int size)
{
    if (source == NULL || destination == NULL || access(source, F_OK) == -1)
        return 0;

    int fd_to = open(destination, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    int fd_from = open(source, O_RDONLY);
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(size));
    ssize_t written;

    if (fd_to < 0 | fd_from < 0)
        return 0;

    read(fd_from, buffer, size);
    written = write(fd_to, buffer, size);
    close(fd_to);
    close(fd_from);
    free(buffer);

    return written;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it is broken?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't create the destination file at all. Sometimes it does but the file size is 0 bytes. And ~10% of the time it works correctly.

Comment: Any reason you are using POSIX functions instead of standard C library functions?

Comment: Add error checkng to all of your functions, then report back to which are triggered when it fails.

Comment: and use stat to find the size of the file so the caller doesnt have to do it (if you dont want to use chunking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a buffer as large as the file is not economical for large buffer values ("large" depending on platform and OS, but I doubt it exceeds, say, one megabyte before hitting diminishing returns). On some systems, you could be allowed to allocate much more than the physical available memory, the buffer being backed up by a swap area **on disk**. At this point if you tried to copy the whole of the file in one fell swoop, you might end up reading and writing most of the file to the swap area, then reading back from the swap area to the new file, effectively doubling (at least) copy times.

So I'd use a loop.

You would also need to check errors in memory allocation and file writing, and consider that size being an `int` might cause problems with large files (2 GB is an accessible file size nowadays, yet it will overflow a 32-bit signed integer).

```
// Copies a part of a file from source to destination
// and returns number of bytes written.
// if input size is < 0, copies the whole file.

ssize_t copy_file(char* source, char* destination, int size)
{
    if ((source == NULL) || (destination == NULL) || (access(source, F_OK) == -1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    #define BUFFER_SIZE 1048576
    char* buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (NULL == buffer) {
        return 0;
    }

    int fd_from = open(source, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_from < 0) {
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
    }
    int fd_to = open(destination, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    if (fd_to < 0) {
        free(buffer);
        // Avoid leaking a file handle in case of error.
        close(fd_from);
        return 0;
    }

    ssize_t written = 0;
    // This checks that size is != 0.
    // As a result, passing a size < 0 will copy the whole source,
    // whatever its length.
    // The condition is written explicitly, deliberately (a simple
    // while(size) might be overlooked or mistaken for a bug).
    while((size > 0)||(size < 0)) {
        int ch_r;
        ch_r = read(fd_from, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (ch_r) {
            if (ch_r != write(fd_to, buffer, ch_r)) {
                // Out of storage space?
                close(fd_from);
                close(fd_to);
                free(buffer);
                unlink(destination);
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            // finished
            break;
        }
        written += ch_r;
        // We do have a problem of integer size. if
        // sizeof(int) is 4 (32bit), files or sizes larger than 2 GB will
        // likely misbehave.
        size -= ch_r;
    }
    close(fd_to);
    close(fd_from);
    free(buffer);
    return written;
}
```

Also, you might find it useful to return the *error status* instead of the size. If you return zero, then you know that the number of written bytes equals the input size. If you need to return both values, you can put the error in a variable passed by pointer:

```
ssize_t copy_file(char* source, char* destination, int size, int *status)
{
    *status = 0; // Begin with "no error"

    ...
    if (NULL == buffer) {
        *status = -8; // -8 stands for "out of memory"
        return 0;
    }

    ...
```

This way, in case of an error, you will know *why* the routine returned zero. Also you will be able to create zero-length files in case of need (the function will return 0, but status will also be 0, indicating that a write of zero bytes is no error).

To copy a regular file, with no need to specify the file size:

```
// Copies a file from source to destination
// and returns number of bytes written.

ssize_t copy_file(char* source, char* destination)
{
    if ((source == NULL) || (destination == NULL) || (access(source, F_OK) == -1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    #define BUFFER_SIZE 1048576
    char* buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (NULL == buffer) {
        return 0;
    }

    int fd_from = open(source, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_from < 0) {
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
    }
    int fd_to = open(destination, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    if (fd_to < 0) {
        free(buffer);
        // Avoid leaking a file handle in case of error.
        close(fd_from);
        return 0;
    }

    ssize_t written = 0;

    // Infinite loop, exiting when nothing more can be read
    for(;;) {
        int ch_r;
        ch_r = read(fd_from, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (ch_r) {
            if (ch_r != write(fd_to, buffer, ch_r)) {
                // Out of storage space?
                close(fd_from);
                close(fd_to);
                free(buffer);
                unlink(destination);
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            // finished
            break;
        }
        written += ch_r;
    }
    close(fd_to);
    close(fd_from);
    free(buffer);
    return written;
}
```

Comment: I see. I had assumed the OP wanted to be able to only copy an area at the beginning of a file, or a finite chunk out of a file of infinite length (e.g. /dev/zero or /dev/urandom). That's why I added in the possibility of specifying a size of -1 to fully copy a file of unknown but finite length. -- *edited answer. Thanks for the heads-up!*

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(size)` returns the size of the datatype of the variable `size`, which would typically be 4 for an `int` - so your buffer always contains 4 bytes. Use `malloc(size)` instead. Also, you only read and write one buffer - you need to use a loop to repeat the process if the file is larger than the buffer size.

Also, use `||` instead of `|` for logical OR in `if (fd_to < 0 | fd_from < 0)`.

Comment: was about to report these two issues :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made those two changes to my code, but it's still not working correctly. Some files still aren't being copied and some are still created with 0 bytes.

Comment: The `size` variable refers to the size in bytes of the entire file. I allocate one buffer that is large enough to hold the entire file contents in memory.

Comment: @Ryan:typically you should check return values for those read and write calls (and all methods in general); especially if I am not wrong read may return fewer bytes than it was told to read-in that case you will need to loop till you make sure you read all

Answer (score 1):

I presume you need to copy a file of arbitrary length, and the *size* argument passed to the function is the buffer size, as opposed to the file size. You need to do `malloc(size)`, not `malloc(sizeof(size))`, btw. Most important, you need a loop containing read() and write(), something like

```
size_t rd_len, wr_len;
do {
    rd_len = read(fd_from, buffer, size);
    wr_len = write(fd_to, buffer, size);
    /* check that wr_len == rd_len */
    written += wr_len;
while (wr_len > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't why it doesn't work (assuming it's correct) but --

Don't try to read the whole file into memory at once. Allocate a fixed size (1000 bytes say) buffer and loop reading a chunk and writing a chunk till end of file.

Comment: Why is it better to repeatedly read and write from a fixed size buffer instead of doing it all at once? Especially considering that I would know the exact size of the file ahead of time.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to not allocate something unless you actually need to allocate something. Fixed-size buffers are fine if size concerns are managed a different way (i.e. by chunking).

Comment: @Ryan, you wont be able to copy huge files, and even if you had enough memory you put a huge load on the system. You dont need all the bytes in memory at once, you only need them one at a time (but that would be very inefficient)

Comment: suggest the buffer be the same size as the related disk block size. (typically 4096 bytes) to minimize the number of disk accesses and OS buffering of odd parts of a disk block.